# How to display a list of data from Javascript into a Select Statement HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, date, drop-down-menu, momentjs

I am using this function using moment.js to display the Mondays of the month, but I am not sure how to store it into a Select statement on HTML.

```
<html>
<body>
  <select id="change">

  </select>
  <br>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    var monday = moment()
        .startOf('month')
        .day("Monday");
    if (monday.date() > 7) monday.add(7,'d');
    var month = monday.month();
    while(month === monday.month()){
        document.getElementById("Change").innerHTML += monday.format("MM-DD") +"<br>";
        monday.add(7,'d');
    }
</script>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mitchellrlee/Luetpgfe/449/#&togetherjs=cIDv1Tnvle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function `add` from the element `select`:

```
select.add(new Option(...));
```

```js
var monday = moment().startOf('month').day("Monday");

if (monday.date() > 7) monday.add(7, 'd');

var month = monday.month();
var select = document.getElementById("change");

while (month === monday.month()) {
  select.add(new Option(monday.format("MM-DD"), monday.format("MM-DD")));
  monday.add(7, 'd');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<select id="change">

  </select>
```